# How can I use data collection from firestore in html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

currently I creating the website using cloud firestore as my database. Right now I can query the data from my collection but it didn't work when I try to display that data on my html web page.

```
const firebase = require("firebase/app")

require("firebase/firestore")

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCxrJbfDOorE9H4E0I2O98tLftoxFAHNLU",
    authDomain: "school-bus-tracking-syst-3ff71.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://school-bus-tracking-syst-3ff71.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "school-bus-tracking-syst-3ff71",
    storageBucket: "school-bus-tracking-syst-3ff71.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "200434933461",
    appId: "1:200434933461:web:4cece32389af487c944c5c",
    measurementId: "G-Q9C278TWTV"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var firestore = firebase.firestore();

const inputTextfield = document.querySelector("#contactnum");

const docRef = firestore.doc("driver/D001");
docRef.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            inputTextfield.innerText = doc.data().contactNo;
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

and my HTML file is

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="contactnum">
<script scr = "./we.js"></script>
```

I tried this but I don't get anything display on my html website. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show your entire HTML code? (evrything between the `<html>..</html>`tags)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1 id = "hotDogOutput">Hot dog status</h1>
<input type = "textfield" id = "lastestHotDofStatus" />
<button id = "saveButton">Save</button>
<button id = "loadButton">Load</button>
<script src = "app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>